# How to get the entire array back back from Firestore and not an object?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

How to get the entire array back back from Firestore and not an object?

I get this object

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zphE1.png]

instead I want an Array

[image]

from my firestore array here

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjqvQ.png]

this is my code so far..

```
fb.usersCollection
    .doc(this.currentUser.uid)
    .collection('fragebogen')
    .doc('fragebogen1')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.data()
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot.data()` returns an object that contains the contents of the entire document.  The keys of the objects are the names of the fields in the document.  So, if the array field in that document is named `arr`, then your array will be in `snapshot.data().arr`.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark it as correct.